# Add new Book for Author

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel so the solution to this may be quite simple. I have an already created Author and I'm trying to add a new book for that Author.

For example, on the Author view there will be an "Add new Book" button. When clicked, you are taken to the "Create new Book" view with the Author id already provided from the previous view.

Author model has a hasMany to Books
Books model has a belongsTo Author

What is the cleanest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$book= new Book(array('name' => 'your new book here'));

$author= Author::find(1);

$book= $author->books()->save($book);
```

You can read more about inserting related models [here in the official Laravel docs.](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models)

Comment: Yeah, I already read that part. My question more relates to the best way to pass the author ID across

Comment: Pass the ID to where? You dont need to pass the ID to the model - Eloquent will link it when you save it through the relationship.

Comment: If I am loading `books.create` how do I know the author id?

Or should I be loading something more like `authors.{id}.create`?

Comment: You should probably do a route like this `books.create.{author}` - and bind the Author model to the route. Then in your function you can do `$author->id`

Comment: I got it working based on your last comment, thanks.